# как исключить значения из датафрейма по условию наличия в словаре?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, словари

есть датафрейм, который хранит в первой колонке различные значения, как исключить те значения, которых нет в ключах словарей, и оставить только соответствующие?
пытался следующим образом, но он полностью чистит колонку, и она вся заполняется nan

```
s_df.loc[s_df[s_df.columns[0]] != t_dict.keys(), s_df.columns[0]] = np.nan
```

Пример:

```
s_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 5, 0, 9, 4],
                     'B': [np.nan, 7, 9, np.nan, 4],
                     'C': [np.nan, np.nan, 8, 9, 0],
                     'D': [7, 7, np.nan, 1, np.nan]
                     })

t_dict = {5: [], 4: []}
```

Comment: пример датафрейма и словара - в вопрос.

Comment: @strawdog, добавил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"a":1,"c":2,"e":3,}
df = pd.DataFrame({0:["a","b","c","d","e"],1:[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

```
   0  1
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  c  3
3  d  4
4  e  5
```

```
res = df.loc[df[0].isin(d.keys())]
```

res:

```
   0  1
0  a  1
2  c  3
4  e  5
```

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы датафрейм не полностью чистился, а менял не соответствующие значения в колонке на nan

Comment: Большое спасибо, использовал s_df.loc[s_df[s_df.columns[0]].isin(t_dict.keys()) == False, s_df.columns[0]] = np.nan, и все сработало

Comment: `.keys()` можно не писать

Answer (score 3):

можно еще попробовать такой вариант:

```
s_df['A'] = s_df['A'].mask(s_df['A'].isin(t_dict))

>>> s_df
'''
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  7.0
1  NaN  7.0  NaN  7.0
2  0.0  9.0  8.0  NaN
3  9.0  NaN  9.0  1.0
4  NaN  4.0  0.0  NaN
```

Comment: Большое спасибо